# C++ - Specify Overloaded Functor or Function When Passing To `std::function`

Tags: c++, casting, overloading, functor, std-function

So I want to pass mathematical functors to `std::function`s.

```
    std::function< double( double ) > squareRoot( std::sqrt );
```

I get an error saying it could not resolve the overload on MSVC and GCC. However this works

```
    std::function< double( double ) > squareRoot( ( double( * )( double ) ) std::sqrt );
    std::cout << squareRoot( 4.0 ) << "\n";
```

Scarily it works if we pass the address of the functor

```
    std::function< double( double ) > squareRoot( ( double( * )( double ) ) &std::sqrt );
    std::cout << squareRoot( 4.0 ) << "\n";
```

Both of the latter (trivial) programs produce valid output.

What is the proper way to specify the particular overload of a functor when passing it to something like `std::function` (bonus if can someone explain the template parameter syntax especially in relation to this)?

**UPDATE 0**

The following works under GCC but not MSVC, so I am updating the title to include functions.

```
std::function< double( double ) > squareRoot( sqrt );
```

**UPDATE 1**

The previous example works under both GCC and MSVC include just `<cmath>` but not when `<math.h>` is included after. Im not sure if I am actually dealing with a function or a functor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've done it (casting `std::sqrt` to the specific function pointer type required) is the correct way to pick out the specific overload you want. As you observed, it works both with and without the explicit `&`. It would be considered better style to use `static_cast<double(*)(double)>` than the C-style cast, in order to avoid accidentally performing a `reinterpret_cast`.

There is no special template parameter syntax here to be aware of. `std::sqrt` is not a template, so trying to specify template parameters (like `std::sqrt<double>`) would not be correct. You also can't explicitly specify the template arguments for the `std::function` constructor (this is a syntactic issue in C++: there is no constructor name to put the template arguments after).

Comment: Thank you! Glad to know I did it the right way. Just one thing for the second part, I was more discussing the way the template argumetns are passed to `std::function` not `std::sqrt` i.e `std::function< double( double ) >` with parenthesis for the variadic instead of CSV. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain `std::function<double(double)>` is correct. The template argument is the function type that the `std::function` object is modelled after. I think it was a bad design decision to be honest (`std::function<R, Arg1, Arg2, ...>` would have been better) but we're stuck with it.

Comment: I feel like that syntactic sugar was added to the language just for `std::function` almost.

Also I noticed this solution isent working under MSVC

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain There's no syntactic sugar. It's just using a function type as a template parameter, which has always been allowed. Anyway, regarding the MSVC issue, I would suggest writing a *different* question (and include the full error message). The question as you originally wrote it has been answered as far as standard C++ goes.

Comment: Could you send me a link to what you mean by function type as template parameter? I would be interested to read it. The closest thing I can think of is at the end of this article `int (*pf)(int)` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters `std::function` has `template< class R, class... Args >` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function ? The reason I thought about it like that is it looks like this syntax `std::function< return_type( argument_type ) >` is just another way of saying `std::function< return_type, argument_type >`
And yes your right.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain The syntax like `double(double)` is a type-id naming a function type. It's different from the pointer-to-function type `double(*)(double)`. There just aren't many places spelling a function type that way is valid, and there were even fewer before C++11 added the `using` syntax for typedefs. It has been valid since long before `boost::function` existed; they just decided to take advantage of it. `std::function<R(A)>` isn't exactly another way of saying `std::function<R,A>`- the two ways require different ways of defining and using `function`, but it could have been either way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, a question I have in response is, according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function the only other definition of `std::function` besides `template< class R, class... Args > class function` is `template< class > class function /*undefined*/` I dont see where this type of type-id fits? Thank you for your responce @aschepler

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain The first one should actually be `template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>` as it is in that link. So whatever argument you pass to the template, it gets pattern matched against `R(Args...)` as part of the deduction process.

Comment: The thing is that `template<class R, class...Args> class function<R(Args...)>` is the syntax for a class template partial specialization. We first need to have something to specialize. So the header declares `template <class> class function;` just to say that it is a class template with one parameter which is a type. But it can't be just any type, it must be a function type so that it can match the actually defined specialization. If you try `function<int>` or some other template argument which is not a match, you just get an error that the class isn't defined.